# If you roll a 1 you roll again

Tags: probability

Suppose you decide to roll a single die $3$ times, and at any time you roll a $1$, you roll the die two more times.

What's the expected number of rolls in this (rather contrived) game?

If I change it to start with the intention of rolling once, and rolling a $1$ instead only adds one more roll, this becomes a relatively straightforward series and I think the answer comes out to be $6/5$ or thereabouts.

But I don't know how to extend the solution to the $(3,2)$ case as I've asked it here, or the general $(m,n)$ case.

I tried to define a random variable $X$ to count the number of rolls and then brute for the probabilities for each non-zero value of $X$, but it seemed too tedious to be the most efficient solution.

Comment: If you start with e.g. $134$ then do you stop or do you go on at least twice because you "earned" $2$ extra throws by the first-thrown $1$?

Comment: You keep going, every $1$ you throw adds another two throws to your pool.

Comment: By linearity of expectation, you only need to consider a single die.

Comment: There is only one die. You start by rolling it 3 times, say you roll 3 4 5. Then because there are no 1s, you stop, and $X = 3$. If the sequence was instead 3 1 2, you get another two rolls, say 3 4. So the sequence is 3 1 2 3 4 and $X = 5$. If one of those two extra rolls was a 1, you get two more rolls and so $X \geq 7$, and so on. I want to know what $E(X)$ is.

Comment: But then also if you roll 1 1 1 on your initial 3 rolls, you get an extra six rolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, by linearity of expectation the result is $3$ times the result for a single die with the same rules.

For a single die, you get $1$ roll no matter what you roll, and then additionally twice the expected value if you roll a $1$, so the expected value $E$ satisfies

$$
E=1+\frac16\cdot2E\;.
$$

The solution is $E=\frac32$, and since you have $3$ of these, you expect to roll the die $\frac92$ times.

Comment: I'm not really sure why it's linear. I mean I understand that expectation is linear but I don't see why this situation is equivalent to multiplying the random variable by 3. How would you do it using that similar method but without starting with just one roll? If we always start with 3 then do we have $E = 3 + P(rolling at least one 1 in the first three rolls)\cdot 2E$? That doesn't give the right value.

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey: I don't understand how you came up with that equation. I don't see how you can do it without making use of the linearity, since starting with $3$ rolls you can end up with various numbers of rolls, and without using linearity you'd have just one equation for several variables, one for each possible number of rolls.

Comment: Yeah that is true. I think I get it now.